# Case expression degrading performance in Correlated Sub query

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

```
SUM((CASE WHEN ([t2].[__measure__8] > 1) THEN (CASE WHEN [t2].[__measure__8] = 0 THEN NULL ELSE (CAST([t2].[__measure__9] as float) / [t2].[__measure__8]) END) ELSE [t2].[__measure__9] END))
```

when I use this calculation above Correlated Subquery which has a group by too . Its is taking more than 5 minutes to receive the result set. Moreover, the inner subset of query retrieves in just 4 sec. Am I missing something else?

What is the best way to write this case expression?

Answer (score 0):

Since you only have 1 condition on your `case` statement, I suggest to use `iif` function instead.

```
sum(
    iif([t2].[__measure__8] > 1,
        iif([t2].[__measure__8] = 0, null, cast([t2].[__measure__9] as float)/[t2].[__measure__8]),
    [t2].[__measure__9])
)
```

Try to break down your query by using `subqueries`, remove the `sum()` first then check the improvements.

Answer (score 0):

Sub case statement looks like unnecessary. You can remove `CASE WHEN [t 2].[_ measure _8] = 0`

```
SUM(CASE 
        WHEN ([t2].[__measure__8] > 1) THEN (CAST([t2].[__measure__9] as float) / [t2].[__measure__8]) 
        ELSE [t2].[__measure__9] 
    END )
```